# How to quantize directions in Canny edge detector in python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scipy, canny-operator

I am trying to understand this implementation of Canny operator in python that 
I found on Rosettacode.org but don't understand how it calculates thetaQ. Why does it use 5 in this formula and how it quantizes direction?
Can anybody help me please?

```
#!/bin/python
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve, gaussian_filter
from scipy.misc import imread, imshow

def CannyEdgeDetector(im, blur = 1, highThreshold = 91, lowThreshold = 31):
    im = np.array(im, dtype=float) #Convert to float to prevent clipping values

    #Gaussian blur to reduce noise
    im2 = gaussian_filter(im, blur)

    #Use sobel filters to get horizontal and vertical gradients
    im3h = convolve(im2,[[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]]) 
    im3v = convolve(im2,[[1,2,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-2,-1]])

    #Get gradient and direction
    grad = np.power(np.power(im3h, 2.0) + np.power(im3v, 2.0), 0.5)
    theta = np.arctan2(im3v, im3h)
    thetaQ = (np.round(theta * (5.0 / np.pi)) + 5) % 5 #Quantize direction

    #Non-maximum suppression
    gradSup = grad.copy()
    for r in range(im.shape[0]):
        for c in range(im.shape[1]):
            #Suppress pixels at the image edge
            if r == 0 or r == im.shape[0]-1 or c == 0 or c == im.shape[1] - 1:
                gradSup[r, c] = 0
                continue
            tq = thetaQ[r, c] % 4

            if tq == 0: #0 is E-W (horizontal)
                if grad[r, c] <= grad[r, c-1] or grad[r, c] <= grad[r, c+1]:
                    gradSup[r, c] = 0
            if tq == 1: #1 is NE-SW
                if grad[r, c] <= grad[r-1, c+1] or grad[r, c] <= grad[r+1, c-1]:
                    gradSup[r, c] = 0
            if tq == 2: #2 is N-S (vertical)
                if grad[r, c] <= grad[r-1, c] or grad[r, c] <= grad[r+1, c]:
                    gradSup[r, c] = 0
            if tq == 3: #3 is NW-SE
                if grad[r, c] <= grad[r-1, c-1] or grad[r, c] <= grad[r+1, c+1]:
                    gradSup[r, c] = 0

.........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atan2` returns a value in the range [-π,π]. The formula `(np.round(theta * (5.0 / np.pi)) + 5)` converts this to the range [0,10], with rounded values. They then take the value modulo 5, which yields an integer in the range [0,4], mapping 5 and 10 to 0, 6 to 1, etc. That is, 0, -π and π are all mapped to the same integer.
Later they take that value modulo 4, which maps the 4 to 0. That is the part I don't understand. It seems wrong to me. Here's the mapping:

[image: plot that maps angle to integer]

You can see that a value just above π/2 gets mapped to 3, and one just below gets mapped to 2. Also, the range of angles mapping to 0 is twice as large as those mapping to other angles. I would have rounded these angles differently.

In any case, the typical implementation of the Canny filter does not quantize angles, instead uses interpolation to read values in between pixels.

Also, the use of the Sobel filter to compute derivatives is strange, especially since they're applied after a Gaussian filter. The derivative of Gaussian filter should be used here instead, to smooth and compute the derivative in one step.

Comment: Great! thanks very much for detail explanation. Regarding using Sobel after Gaussian, It is something mentioned in OpenCV document: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen this in a lot of places. Canny's paper has been cited 28,000+ times, I bet very few of those people actually bothered reading his paper. Here it is: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/55e6/6333402df1a75664260501522800cf3d26b9.pdf

Comment: Just for completeness of the answer: the paper goes on for several pages to develop the ideal edge localization filter, then he suggests that the derivative of Gaussian is an efficient approximation to that ideal.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I cannot rate your answer, cause I am a new member and system doesn't let me do that.  Thx much again. I will try to implement it just using Gaussian.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't let me do that. It records my cast but not displaying it publicly due to my low reputation (less than 15). Sorry about that . :(